# Qt Quick hit-test in the Item tree

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have some items in the scene:

```
Rectangle {
    x: 20
    y: 20
    width: 20
    height: 20
    color: 'red'

    Rectangle {
        x: 5
        y: 10
        width: 5
        height: 5
        color: 'green'
    }
}
```

now I would like to know: given a (x, y) coordinate, which is the topmost visible item that renders something at that coordinate?

E.g.:

- for `(21, 21)` that would be the red `Rectangle`
- for `(26, 32)` that would be the green `Rectangle`
- for `(15, 15)` that would be nothing

does Qt Quick offers a simple function to do this?

If not, consider the possibility to add `MouseArea`s that fill the rectangles.
Can I synthesize a *press* event with specific (x, y) coordinate? This would be even better.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is amongst the methods of [Qml Item](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html) . You should take a look at the [childAt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#childAt-method) method or the [visibleChildren](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#visibleChildren-prop) property.

Comment: ...almost good! It seems to disregard the `z` property of items, and instead it picks the "first" visible in tree order, so it will not return an item with higher z declared after, but instead it will return the occluded item.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Item.childAt(...)` is broken in this regard, and it has a [bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-23745) opened 10 years ago and not yet fixed, I came up with this workaround:

```
function traverseItemTreeWithClipping(item, pt, f, rootItem) {
    rootItem = rootItem || item
    var p = item.mapFromItem(rootItem, pt)
    var inItemRect = p.x >= 0 && p.y >= 0 && p.x < item.width && p.y < item.height
    if(item.clip && !inItemRect) return
    f(item, p, inItemRect)
    for(var i = 0; i < item.children.length; i++)
        traverseItemTreeWithClipping(item.children[i], pt, f, rootItem)
}

function hitTest(rootItem, pt) {
    var result = undefined
    var z = -Infinity
    traverseItemTreeWithClipping(rootItem, pt, (item, p, inItemRect) => {
        if(item.visible && item.z >= z && inItemRect) {
            result = item
            z = item.z
        }
    })
    return result
}
```

which takes into account the `z` property of items, returning the truly visible Item.